# Counter example for theorem 2.18 in A computational introduction to number theory and algebra

Tags: number-theory

This is a theorem from [V. Shoup. A computational introduction to number theory and algebra.](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshoup.net%2Fntb%2Fntb-v2.pdf&ei=g4wvVav1EsjzasLbgZAH&usg=AFQjCNEtRfTiiD79uwmSET9YPGcO_KPBgg&sig2=nsskjUzrJZrTJqInVBB_tA)

[image]

I have a counter-example: $\beta = 6, p = 7$, and $36 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Comment: Note that $\beta$ is taken in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, *not* in $\Bbb{Z}$. This means that $\beta = [x]_p$, the residue class modulo $p$ of some $x  \in \Bbb{Z}$. Hence $\beta = [6]_7 = [-1]_7$ is perfectly valid... In other words, you should read every equality involving $\beta$ with $\pmod{p}$ at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$6 \equiv -1 \pmod{7}$$

.....